# How to pass embedded JSON using C# web client

Tags: c#, .net, json, webclient, javascriptserializer

I need to pass embedded JSON file through the API.To achieve that I used following code

```
public static string EvaluateRating(string jsonFile,string vKey, string mobileNo, string nic)
{
    try
    {
        object input = new
        {
            ErrorMessage = "",
            ErrorStatus = false,
            ValidationDataDetails = new
            {
                SessionID = "Ses21",
                ValidatiorKey = vKey.Replace("\"", "")
            },
            onlineRequestFields = new
            {
                SelectedProduct = 162,
                JsonFile = jsonFile
            },
        };

        string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        WebClient client = webClient;
        client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl + "/EvaluateRating", inputJson);
        return json;
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(webEx);
    }
    return null;
}
```

here I passing embedded JSON as a parameter.

parameter `jsonFile` string as follows,

```
{\"evaluation\":{\"numeric\":[{\"@parameter-id\":\"2657\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Monthly Income\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2614\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Existing Financial\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2608\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Basic Salary\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2661\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Existig Card\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2609\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Fixed Allowances\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2611\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Other Income \"}]}}
```

After passing `JSONFile` The value of the `inputJson` show as follows (part of the value in run-time)

```
{\r\n \\\"@parameter-id\\\": \\\"2657\\\",\r\n \\\"@new-value\\\": \\\"\\\",\r\n \\\"@label\\\": \\\"Monthly Income - PersonalAdvances\\\"
```

which makes error,because API not accept `\\\`, when I set the JsonFile as static as follows, API return **expected output without an error**.

```
JsonFile = "{\"evaluation\":{\"numeric\":[{\"@parameter-id\":\"2657\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Monthly Income\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2614\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Existing Financial\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2608\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Basic Salary\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2661\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Existig Card\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2609\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Fixed Allowances\"},{\"@parameter-id\":\"2611\",\"@new-value\":\"\",\"@label\":\"Other Income \"}]}}",
```

I think after `Serialize` object input becomes like this,

```
{\r\n \\\"@parameter-id\\\": \\\"2657\\\",\r\n \\\"@new-value\\\": \\\"\\\",\r\n \\\"@label\\\": \\\"Monthly Income - PersonalAdvances\\\"
```

So then, how to pass this embedded JSON file using C# `WebClient`